# Allow user to select a file and read it

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an app where the user can browse the files on his phone and select one. Then I'd like to open the selected file and read it. It sounds simple but I'm stuck. Here is the code I use for allowing the user to select the file :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
//intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

I don't understand why, when I execute this code i can browse file in my download folder (on my phone) but I can't select anything in it. I have all the required permission in my manifest but it still doesn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: Remove `setType()` or use `setType("*/*")`. `file/*` is not a valid MIME type.

Comment: but I only want the user to open .txt files

Comment: Then use `setType("text/plain")`.

Comment: Yeah it works ! Thank you very much (you can post it as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setType()` on an `Intent`, you need to provide a valid MIME type or MIME type pattern. There is no official MIME type starting with `file/`, and so a MIME type pattern of `file/*` is unlikely to match anything.

> but I only want the user to open .txt files

You cannot filter `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` by file extension, as there does not have to be a file extension, or even a filename. What you *can* do is filter on MIME type, and the MIME type for plain text is `text/plain`. If you wanted to support other sorts of text (e.g., HTML), you might use the MIME type pattern of `text/*`.